# How to fill a list with missing values

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, spyder

I'm trying to read out of an gpx-file, now the speed value won't have an constant appearing in the file. When i safe the values, i can only safe them in a full list:

```
speed []
for speeds in elements:

                   speed.append(speeds.text)
                   new = int((speeds.sourceline)*0.132)
                   speedline.append(new)
for elevation in elements:
   elevation.append(elevation.text)
```

problem is: for example len(hdop) = 1000 and len(speed) just 700
so my solution would be, create a new list where the speed is in the file->the speedline-list

Now i tried some functions to get a new list of speed that has the same length like the elevation list, but none of them will work, please help me:

Here is my complete working script:

```
def komplettlist(speed,speedline,grenze):
i = 0
newdict = {speedline[1::],speed[1::]}
for i in range(grenze):
    i = i+1
    if newdict.has_key(i):
        print("all good")
    if newdict.has_key(i) == False:
        newdict.add(i,"0")

return(newdict)


    #if speedline[i] != i:
        #speedline.insert(i,i)
     #   print(speedline[i], i)
      #  speedline.insert(i,i)
       # i = speedline[i]

def ergänzedict(dict, grenze):
  index = 0
  while index < (grenze):
    index = index +1
    key = dict.keys()
    value = dict.values()
    if key[index] == index:
        print("das klappt")

    if key[index] != index:
        dict[index] = 0
        print("das nicht",key[index],index)
        print(key[index])
        print(index)
        #for key, value in sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda item: 
item[1]):
         #   print("%s: %s" % (key, value))
 def ergänzeliste(newlist,grenze):
indexi = 1

#print ('Index of chemistry', newlist.index(indexi))
print ('Index of C#', newlist.index(1))
while index < (grenze):
        indexi = indexi+1
        doubleindex = indexi*2
        if (newlist[indexi]) == indexi:
            print("das klappt")

        if (newlist[indexi]) != indexi:

            print("das nicht",newlist[indexi],indexi)
print(len(newlist)) 
return()
```

i expected an speed list with the same size like hdop, only with 0 values, where the file has no information about the speed

```
def findewasneues(root):
    #print(etree.iselement(root))
    #if len(root):
     #   print("Root has children)")
    ns1 ="{http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1}hdop"
    ns2 ="{http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1}ele"
    ns3 ="{http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1}time"
    ns4 ="{http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1}extensions"
    ns5 ="{http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1}speed"
    wptID = []
    Gesamt = []
    hdop = []
    ele = []
    speed = []
    time = []
    lat = []
    lon = []
    speed = []
    speedline = []
    e= 0

    for trk in root:
        #print(trk.tag)
        for trkseg in trk:
            #print(trkseg.tag)
            for trkpt in trkseg:
                trkpt.get("lat")
                trkpt.get("lon")
                #print(trkpt.get("lat"))
                #print(trkpt.get("lon"))
                lat.append(trkpt.get("lat"))
                lon.append(trkpt.get("lon"))

               #print(trkpt.tag)
                for elements in trkpt: # elements: ele,time,hdop,extenstions



                   #print(elements.tag)
                   #Gesamt = Gesamt.append(elements.text)
                  # print(elements.text)
                   #print(elements.tag)
                   #if elements.tag == "{http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1}speed" or elements.tag == "{http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1}extensions" :

                     # speed.append(elements.text)
                   if elements.tag == ns1 :
                      hdop.append(elements.text)



                   for speeds in elements:
                       e = e +1
                       speed.append(speeds.text)
                       new = int((speeds.sourceline)*0.131)
                       speedline.append(new)
                       #print(new)
                       #print(speeds.sourceline)

                       #print(speeds.text)

                      #print(elements.tag)
    #dict = {speedline,speed}

    neu =list(enumerate(speedline))
    neu2 = []
    neu3 = []
    for e in neu:
        if e not in neu2:
            neu2.append(e)
            neu3.append(e)
    #print(neu3[0][2])
    #leng = len(neu3/2)
   # e = 0


    list4 = []
    diff = len(hdop)-len(neu3)
    print(diff)
    d = 0
    for d in range(diff):
        list4.append(0)
        d = d +1

    #print(list4)
    #print(len(speed))#237 inhalt: speedwerte
    kts = []
    spl = []
    for e in neu3:
        kts.append(e[0])#keytospeedline
        spl.append(e[1])#speedline
    print(len(list4))#60 inhalt: nullen
    #print(len(kts))#237 inhalt: ids zu den wptids
    print(len(spl))#237 inhalt: wptids
    print(kts)
    print(spl)
    newspeedlist =coolmethod(speed,kts,spl,list4)#insertmissingzeroelemntstospeedlistfunction

    #print(newspeedlist)
    #print(len(newspeedlist))



       #liste1: die speed liste
    def coolmethod(speed,kts,spl,list4):
        nl=[]
        e = 0
        b = len(list4)#anzfehlendereinträge
        a = len(speed)#anzspeedeinträge
        einträge = a+b#anzahl gesamteinträge
        print(einträge)
        for e in kts:
                if e < spl[e]:
                    nl.append("0")
                #if kts[e] >= spl[e]:
                nl.append(speed[e])
                e = e+1

        return(nl)
```

output:
60
297
60
237
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236]
[7, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 121, 129, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 196, 204, 206, 207, 208, 209, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 276, 277, 278]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'd recommend adding a tag to your question with the programming language you are writing in. This enables syntax highlighting and might help people who are skilled in your language find your question.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We cannot run your "complete working script".